# How do I insulate skylight with limited attic access?

Tags: skylight

Roofer installed two Velux skylights recently, but left us to do the interior finishing. I think we have a plan for the skylight shafts now: basically going to make a wood frame attached to the curb 1/4” or so down from the glass and drywall up to it so the top of the drywall fits securely into the wood frame. But maybe there is a better way?

But now we are wondering about how to best insulate the drywall shaft? The attic access here is pretty limited since it’s sloped I’m not sure we can really get to it from the attic. Or is such a small shaft space that the batting insulation that’s already there will be fine? Any ideas? What r-value should we looking to achieve? Also what about vapor barrier?

Here’s some pictures: [photo of skylight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6GJk.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I just used 6" paper faced fiberglas batts stapled to wood framing , nothing special .  No problems in over 20 years.

Comment: @user131879 You can install the batts while standing on a ladder from inside the skylight well, and never have to enter the attic at all.

Comment: I have a steep pitch so had east access in attic.